# Why was this flag declined?

Tags: support, flagging

[Is there any way to tell if someone has been through our hotel room?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/36059/is-there-any-way-to-tell-if-someone-has-been-through-our-hotel-room/59035#59035)

I flagged this specific answer as being needed to be deleted, as the answer could not stand on its own, as the answer relied on a resource no longer available or accessible.

I was under the assumption that answers that cannot hold their own without the resource should be deleted. This is no different than answers that say something along the likes of "Here, check out this video that explains everything" when the video in question is deleted, or "This page has all the tips and tricks regarding your question" when said page is no longer available on the internet.

Comment: Didn't handle the flag, but I've found and emailed the developer to see if he can update it or if it's gone for good.

Comment: Regardless, I don't think emailing the developer is the right way to go.  Say the developer re-adds the app, and a few years from now, the app disappears again. Then we have reached the problem once again and have to constantly re-address it until it is gone for good. I still think that it would do more good to have the answer deleted -- it provides no useful information if the mention of the app were taken out.  Someone coming into this site 1,2,5 years down the road will take more practical answers, and not "here's an app, this is what it does, use it" sorts of answers.

Comment: Sure, but it may at least help the link for now.  It might just be renamed, and then we're good to go.  It's not a wrong answer, even if it is less practical, no?  That's what voting's for.

Comment: It's not just a matter of being less practical, it's that the answer completely folds without the link to the app.  The answer is essentially "This is my app, it solves the problem you have, this app does x, y, and z".  Take out the app, and the answer becomes "This is the problem you have, this thing that no longer exists does x, y, and z".

Comment: One could read it as "I solved it by developing an app myself and it works this way". The answer allows anyone to develop an app with the same features - if one would like one.

Comment: @MikaelDúiBolinder That's a huge stretch, and would still qualify as a terrible answer.  "Here, I have a concept of an app you could use that would help solve your problem, but you need to design and implement it yourself :)"

Comment: @yuritsuki with programming skills becoming more and more common I'd say that's acceptable. Programming is now taught to every child in Sweden in elementary school (probably just some shitty Python but still programming).